# Minimal command to make a copy of a file

Tags: bash, command-line, cp

I often find myself copy-pasting long path in order to create a copy of a file

```
cp /path/to/file/file1 /path/to/file/file1.bkp
```

Is there an alternative utility that will NOT require me to type the path/to/file twice?
Something like -

```
nameOfExecutible /path/to/file/file1 'bkp'
```

Note: I don't want to do a `cd` to `file1`s parent directory.

Comment: How is this Question about copying files (with `cp` being the solution) a duplicate of a Question about using path within `mv` command? I suggest this valuable Question be re-opened.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes,

`cp /path/to/file/file1{,.kbp}`

That will get expanded automatically to `cp /path/to/file/file1 /path/to/file/file1.kbp`

Comment: Thanks. That saves so much time! Is there a terminology for those brackets?

Comment: The bash shell is expanding the expression in the curly braces prior to exec'ing cp. You can find it covered in the bash manual, or google for "bash brace expansion"

Comment: bash brace expansion [url](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)